# Google Classroom API usage (get information about courses)

Tags: google-classroom

with all that covid-19 thing I want to make something that tracks classroom courses that i am subscribed to and take some information like this:

**Example:**

- **¡Hey you have a new assignment from `{teacher name}`.**
- **Title: `{HOMEWORK TITLE}`**
- **Expire date: `{DATE WHEN THE ASSIGNMENT EXPIRES}`**

Is it possible to get that information from the Google Classroom API or should I change the way I take the information?